# Which items are common from exploring buildings?

Tags: die2nite

Exploring certain buildings in the wastes often gives a certain type of item, i.e. you'll get various alcoholic items from searching a Shady Bar. What are the other building types and the items associated with exploring them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the list of all buildings](http://translate.google.com/translate?act=url&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ftwinpedia.com%2Fhordes%2Fbatiments) found in the world beyond.  It is translated from the French version already, however some of the buildings names will be different in our version of the game.  It is easy to work out what each building is, and certainly this is the most detailed and accurate list that exists as far as I know, as well as having all the info listed on 1 page rather than seperate links.

Answer (score 2):

There is great list here: [Special Zones](http://www.zaxarinka.com/d2n-desert.html?start=2).

Comment: I just realized that it is not 100% correct :-( I just found a chest in a Home Depot, and that does not match the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is correlation between buildings and contents thereof. For Hordes, this has been extensively explored on [WikiHordes.](http://wikihordes.wetpaint.com/page/Les+b%C3%A2timents) It should be *mostly* valid for the English versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The items you get from buildings are mostly common sense. So if you're searching an ambulance you'll find mostly bandages and drugs. If you search an old pump you'll find mostly water and some pipes.

Besides the french list there is also [one for the german version of Die2Nite](http://nobbz.de/wiki/index.php/Ruinen), you should be able to understand that one with some online translation tools.